# PHP Error when posting RSS feed data

Tags: php, rss

I'm trying to post a blog to my website. I downloaded Simplepie and followed the directions on the website, but I keep getting these errors. Being new to PHP, I'm not exactly sure what they mean. Any help?

> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /hermes/bosweb/web177/b1775/ipg.waldropcom/php/test.php on line 7
>
> Warning: require_once(http://www.waldrop.com/php/autoloader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /hermes/bosweb/web177/b1775/ipg.waldropcom/php/test.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'http://www.waldrop.com/php/autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.2.17/lib/php') in /hermes/bosweb/web177/b1775/ipg.waldropcom/php/test.php on line 7

Comment: Post your code as part of your question and we may be able to help - otherwise we're like the blind in a minefield...

Answer (score 0):

Probably your application trying to include a remote file but it's failing. You need to enable [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) and [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) settings in php.ini to require or include remote files.

Comment: I checked and found allow_url_fopen is set to on....however, there isn't anything for allow_url_include at all...would I just add it to it....is there a safer way to use a parser for rss content? I read that the fopen and include make it a lot easier for your site to be hacked. Thanks!